# In APEX 5.1 Master/Detail form, how can I force a Detail record to be created depending on a value in the Master

Tags: oracle, master-detail, oracle-apex-5.1

Some rows in my Master table require a row in the Detail table, while others don't.  When a new Master record is created, how can I force creation of a Detail row, depending on the value of a column in the Master row?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Process that will run on page submit that will insert it.

Set its sequence so that it executes after all the other DML processes (including the Detail tabular form or IG processes) have completed.

Put a Condition on it so it only runs if no records are found in the Detail table. This could be based on a simple "No Rows Returned" condition.

You will need to ensure that the relevant data from the Master table is available, e.g. the Master record ID. You may need to check the **Return Key Into Item** property on the DML process.

Comment: There is additional data on the detail row that the user needs to enter-- only if the master column value is 'POPSEL' , then the user needs to create a detail row with information about the popsel (other values don't require a detail record),  So I need to do more than just insert a row on submit (if I understand you properly).  I need to force the user to enter the detail information.

Comment: In that case I would consider adding the required additional fields so they must be entered on a new record.

Comment: When I make columns in the detail row required,  the user is forced to create a detail row even when a detail row shouldn't exist.  I can force a detail row for all master rows, but I can't seem to figure how to force a detail row only for specific master rows. Is there any way I can make whether a field is required conditional on another value?